# How does the Oracle Enterprise Single Sign-on Logon Manager attach itself to a VM?

Tags: java, security, single-sign-on

Today we noticed that a NullPointerException occurred in our software. But the origin wasn't in any package we included.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.passlogix.vgo.ho.ApplicationWindow.getWindow(ApplicationWindow.java:178)
at com.passlogix.vgo.ho.Jho.addApplicationWindow(Jho.java:453)
at com.passlogix.vgo.ho.WindowScanner.run(WindowScanner.java:697)
```

A quick search on the internet shows that this seems to be a single sign on mechanism related to Oracle. Or more specific the Oracle Enterprise Single Sign-on Logon Manager.

Somehow they manage to hook into our VM and scan what happens for whatever reason.
From what i see they have an AWT event interceptor and could be keylogging and screen grabbing without us noticing. The only reason not to freak out right now is that it is an official Oracle product and "they wouldn't do that".

This is of course a major back door to our program and i want to understand what mechanism they use to get into our VM and how to protect our programm from attacks by malware.

Comment: This is just a guess, but Oracle wrote the logon manager and Oracle maintains the source code for the Java virtual machine.  Oracle could have put hooks in the JVM for their logon manager.  As far as protecting your Java application, another Java application can use reflection to see inside your application.

Comment: Don't we have to open debug ports, etc for other applications to attach themselves to our running application? Another application could probably easily put a wrapper around ours, but this is not the case here.